# Is there any way to access the address of private instance variable of any class in objective c runtime?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is there way to access address of private instance variable  of any class by using objective c runtime?

for example:

```
 self.navigationItem.title
```

Is there any way to get address of _title ivar of UINavigationItem class?

Thanks

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why?

Answer (score 4):

Obvious observations: self.navigationItem.title may not be an instance variable, as a getter can do anything it likes to generate a result and the dot notation just calls the getter. Even if it is an instance variable in this version of the OS it may not have been in the past and may not be in the future. Even if title is directly backed by an instance variable, it may not be named _title — it could be called anything whatsoever.

Even in the case where you do know for certain that a class has a particular instance variable, the relevant mechanisms are removed as of Objective-C 2.0. Under the older runtime you could have used:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

...
Ivar instanceVariable = class_getInstanceVariable([instance class], "varName");
// yes, really, a C-style string

NSLog(@"offset of that var is %d", instanceVariable->ivar_offset);
```

Or, similarly:

```
struct exampleClassStruct
{
    @defs(exampleClass);
};
// this is now a struct with the same layout all the same instance variables
// as exampleClass
```

However, you'll now be met with errors like "Invalid application of @defs in non-fragile ABI". So, in conclusion: you can't do what you want to do. Probably the closest thing is to use [class_GetProperty](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/class_getProperty), which — like dot notation — doesn't care about memory layouts or whether the thing has the same name or even is really an instance variable. Failing that, class_getInstanceMethod (on the same page) can be used to get a C function pointer to the getter.

EDIT: a quick extra observation, after following alastair's comment below, is that the [runtime](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html) provides `id object_getIvar(id object, Ivar ivar)` ([link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/object_getIvar)) and a set equivalent, which are the opaque ways to get and set instance variables on a particular class given that their address is now obscured. Those take the Ivar that you get from either 
`class_getInstanceVariable` or `object_getInstanceVariable` so probably aren't doing any sort of complicated lookup, and explain why you can still get Ivars even though the associated struct now has no public members whatsoever.

EDIT2: please see discussion with alastair below; the final parameter of `object_getInstanceVariable` and/or the result of `ivar_getOffset` may be usable to do what you want, depending on your interpretation of the documentation. Supposing you adopt the same reading as alastair, then either of the following would do what you want (coded extemporaneously):

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

void *pointerToInstanceVariableA(id object, const char *variableName)
{
    Ivar instanceVar = class_getInstanceVariable([object class], variableName);
    return (unsigned char *)object + ivar_getOffset(instanceVar);
}

void *pointerToInstanceVariableB(id object, char *variableName)
{
    void *returnValue;
    Ivar instanceVar = object_getInstanceVariable(object, variableName, &returnValue);
    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: The Objective-C 2.0 runtime still has functions for this kind of thing; check out `object_getInstanceVariable()`, for instance.

Comment: That seems to return an 'Ivar' though, and if you check out objc/runtime.h (/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/usr/include/objc/runtime.h on my machine) you'll see that every public field of struct objc_ivar, a pointer to which is typedef'd as Ivar, is unavailable in Objc2. Relevant lines are 43 and 439 to 446. That said, object_getIvar seems to be the new fastest way to read the value of an instance variable and is no doubt what is being used underneath the Objective-C sheen.

Comment: You don’t actually need to use the `Ivar` return; the `outValue` argument lets you obtain the (pointer-sized) value directly. Also, there are some other functions for detaling with `Ivar`s (e.g. `ivar_getName()`, `ivar_getTypeEncoding()` and `ivar_getOffset()`).

Comment: @alastair: I found the text "On return, contains a pointer to the value of the instance variable." to be suspicious when compared to e.g. "...contains a pointer to the instance variable." — it sounds like they don't mean to imply that the pointer would necessarily still point to the value if the value is changed. The ivar_getOffset documentation states "For instance variables of type id or other object types, call object_getIvar and object_setIvar instead of using this offset to access the instance variable data directly." which reads as a command not merely a suggested alternative.

Comment: On further reflection, I appreciate the ivar_getOffset documentation may be trying to distinguish between a pointer to an object and a pointer to a pointer to an object, but I'm not completely persuaded. I've edited my answer, hopefully appropriately, to reflect the extra information you've supplied — I hope fairly.

Comment: @alastair:@Tommy:Thanks for valuable input. I really appreciate your help. It's really improve my knowledge about objective c run time. Tommy your pointerToInstanceVariableB function work for me. Thanks a lot :).

Answer (score -1):

I have a view controller and I needed the property from the base class. It's name was defined as so

```
@property ( nonatomic, strong ) NSString *ModuleName;
```

the code to access it without any knowledge of the class

The code to get an instance of a custom view controller

```
    id viewCtrl = [appDelegate returnTestView];
```

now I grab the value ( no knowledge of any class )

```
    Ivar instanceVariable = class_getInstanceVariable([viewCtrl class], "ModuleName");
    NSString *privateValue = (NSString *) object_getIvar(viewCtrl, instanceVariable);
    NSLog(@"Your value is %@", privateValue);
```

The actual method in my appDelegate is

```
- (id)returnTestView {
    return [[TestViewController alloc] init];
}
```

The init of my custom view controller

```
@interface TestViewController : UIViewController

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        self.ModuleName = @"Hello World";
    }
    return self;
}
```